# Tamaño especifico para <td> en una tabla HTML JS

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

Resulta que tengo esta tabla:

```
<table  class="table tablaReversible table-responsive" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre Material</th>
                        <th>Num Parte</th>
                        <th>Aprobado</th>
                        <th>Aros</th>
                        <th>Revision</th>
                        <th>Diametro</th>
                        <th>Largo</th>
                        <th>Top</th>
                        <th>Bottom</th>
                        <th>Otros</th>
                        <th>Uni/Cajas</th>
                        <th>F-IPR-001 Orden Interna</th>
                        <th>F-IPR-002 Plano de Corte</th>
                        <th>F-IPR-004 Plano Marcación</th>
                        <th>F-IPR-003 Instruc. de Trabajo</th>
                        <th>F-IPR-005 Plano Especifica</th>
                        <th>DS001 Instruction Sheet</th>
                        <th>Drawing</th>
                        <th>Última orden emitida</th>
                        <th>Cliente Final</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach(var m in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@m.Id</td>
                        <td><b>@m.NombreMaterialUnion</b></td>
                        <td>@m.NumParte</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (m.Aprobado.HasValue)
                            {
                                @m.Aprobado.Value.ToShortDateString()
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>@m.Aros</td>
                        <td>@m.Revision</td>
                        <td>@m.Diametro</td>
                        <td>@m.Largo</td>
                        <td>@m.Top</td>
                        <td>@m.Bottom</td>
                        <td>@m.Otras</td>
                        <td>@m.UniCajas</td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button></td>
                        <td>11/11/2019</td>
                        <td>NULL</td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

La cual esty agrupando usando DataTable jQuery asi, con el fin de mostrar solo X nombre como cabecera

```
$('.tablaReversible').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 1 },
            { "visible": false, "targets": 0 },
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc'],[3, 'asc']],
        rowGroup: {
            startRender: function (rows, group) {
                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append('<td width="200" height="5" bgcolor="#78923B"><font size="2">' + group + '</font></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
            },
            endRender: null,
            dataSrc: 1
        }
    });
```

al final me queda algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fila verde se genera en esta linea:

```
.append('<td width="200" height="5" bgcolor="#78923B"><font size="2">' + group + '</font></td>')
```

Existe una forma de especificar de que esa fila sea menos alta y que el nombre se expanda y no quede tan "compactado" ?

Gracias

Comment: Haz probado ya las tablas de Admin LTE?

Comment: @MiguelClavijo no, basicamente son las mismas, datatables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizas sea una tonteria lo que diga, pero y si le añades un cierre de tr al final del ultimo append de td? es decir:

```
 .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
 .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td></tr>')
```

Soy nuevo en stackoverflow, asi que disculpa si me expreso mal...

Answer (score 1):

Añade un tr, en puesto de un td.

```html
.append('<tr width="200" height="5" bgcolor="#78923B"><td><font size="2">' + group + '</font></td></tr>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que añadir un 'tr' que envuelva al td y darle estilo también:

```
 .append('<tr width="100%"><td bgcolor="#78923B"><font size="2">' + group + '</font></td></tr>')
```

Answer (score -1):

Intenta Aplicando estilo a tu cabecera.

```
<th style="width: 20%">Num Parte</th>
```

Comment: Estimado, te invito a ver [cómo  responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y aplicarlo en tu respuesta, dado que no muestra específicamente la resolución del problema